# Apple pay billing address in valid in @paytabs/react-native-paytabs

Tags: react-native, applepay, applepayjs

I'm trying to implement Apple pay with Paytabs using with @paytabs/react-native-paytabs library and getting the error of Billing Address is invalid

I am using the sandbox for testing with the following documentation https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/

[image: Error getting in apple pay]